# What is the distinction between detaching, jettisoning, and dumping?

Tags: terminology

What is the difference between the terms *detach*, *jettison*, and *dump*?

Related Aviation.SE question: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/22903

---

Examples of using the term "detach":

- [Why was the Friendship 7 Mercury heat shield detachable?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22318/26446)
- [How do Hayabusa-2's DCAM's work? (detachable cameras)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35309/26446)

Comment: The aviation.SE question seems to have be definitively and clearly answered years ago, despite the answers not having been accepted. Can you provide a context for the use of "detach"? It's extremely hard to make nuanced distinctions between related terms without context.

Comment: I think the difference **is** the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the Aviation.SE answers suggest, the distinction between a jettison and a dump is that *dump* refers to release of uncontained liquid (examples: a fuel dump, a wastewater dump) while a *jettison* is a release of a solid object -- maybe an empty fuel tank; historically, jettison was a nautical term meaning ["a voluntary sacrifice of cargo to lighten a ship's load in time of distress"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jettison), but in spaceflight a jettison is usually a planned action.

Both *dump* and *jettison* connote that the released item is not particularly useful or valuable. One might recover a jettisoned fuel tank for reuse, or observe the behavior of a dumped fluid, but those aren't part of the primary function of the vehicle.

In contrast, *detach*, to me, suggests that the detached item may have an ongoing function after detachment, and/or that it may be reattached at a point in the future. The Hayabusa detachable camera takes photos after detachment, serving a useful active function, rather than being an inert object. The Mercury heat shield doesn't actually leave the spacecraft, so "detached" is arguably the wrong term; it's released from its normal position, but still connected via the landing bag.

As with all natural language, these terms are a little fuzzy, as are the categories of things they refer to, so it wouldn't be surprising to see them applied in other ways.

Answer (score 2):

Broadly speaking, "detaching" is the act of unfastening something, whereas "jettisoning" is to send away a thing. You have to detach something in order to jettison it.

The general distinction between "jettisoning" and "dumping" as described at Aviation holds up pretty well in the Space Exploration context, I think.

For clarity, "jettisoning" a fuel tank would be to send away the tank itself, and "dumping" a fuel tank would be emptying the fuel without sending away the tank.